# org.apache.struts.action does not exist

Tags: struts, struts-1

Below i am giving my code it shows some error it says that `org.apache.struts.action` does not exist what can i do for pls tell me the solution ....

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import org.apache.struts.action.Action;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionMapping;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForward;

public class LoginAction extends org.apache.struts.action.Action {

    /* forward name="success" path="" */
    private final static String SUCCESS = "success";


    public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm  form,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws Exception {
             LoginBean loginbean=(LoginBean)form;
             String uname=loginbean.getLogin();
             String pass=loginbean.getPass();
             HttpSession session=request.getSession();
             ArrayList al=new ArrayList();
             al.add(uname);//User Name
             al.add("1");//User Id
             al.add("A");//User Level Means Admin Or Simple User

             if(uname.equalsIgnoreCase("Admin")&& pass.equals("admin"))
             {
                 session.setAttribute("admin",al.get(0));
                 response.sendRedirect("main.jsp");
             }
             else
             {
                 session.removeAttribute("admin");
                 response.sendRedirect("index.jsp?error=notvalid");
             }

        return mapping.findForward(SUCCESS);
    }
}
```

Below i am giving my code it shows some error it says that org.apache.struts.action does not exist what can i do for pls tell me the solution ....

Comment: Why do you both send a redirect *and* return a mapping? You should do one or the other.

Comment: Where it shows error in the code or in the logs?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the Struts jars to the classpath.

Comment: @puneet: You could start with the official web page: http://struts.apache.org/#Newbies

Comment: i did the things now it saying jakarta.apache.org/struts/tags-bean cannot be resolved in either web.xml

Comment: jakarta.apache.org/struts/tags-bean cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
exactly this showing

Comment: @puneet: You need to create an XML mapping file for Struts. Check this tutorial: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/struts_2/struts_quick_guide.htm

Comment: @puneet: You do need some xml files, such as struts.xml or web.xml. It's too complex to explain it here, but the last link I published shows how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to configure server, This worked in my case

Right-click on your project in the Project Explorer.
Select Properties.
In the Properties dialog, go to Java Build Path.
Select the Libraries tab.
Click on Add Library....
Choose Server Runtime and click Next.
Select your JBoss Server Runtime (e.g., JBoss EAP x.x Runtime) and click Finish.
Click Apply and Close.